# Qual a classe gramatical da palavra "então" no diálogo abaixo?

Tags: classe-gramatical, semântica

- A. "Por mim, não há necessidade de o aparelho de ar condicionado estar ligado."
- B. "É, não está calor suficiente para isso."
- A. "Eu posso desligá-lo **então**?" (assim mesmo, sem vírgula precedendo)

O meu Aurélio apresenta as seguintes categorias gramaticais para a palavra: advérbio, interjeição e substantivo.  "Então", no exemplo acima tem uma carga semântica indicativa de que "A" entendeu que pode desligar o aparelho e espera apenas uma confirmação de "B". Não me parece tratar-se de um advérbio ou uma interjeição. Muito menos um substantivo. Qual seria a sua classe gramatical?

**p.s. em 18/03/2018.**  Professor [**Leo Ricino**](https://www.recantodasletras.com.br/autor.php?id=15186) afirma em um texto publicado em revista de língua portuguesa que "todas as palavras e expressões são classificadas de acordo com as finalidades para as quais foram criadas. Se uma palavra serve para conectar outras palavras, ela é classificada, por exemplo, como preposição, conjunção, pronome relativo e até verbo de ligação; se serve para qualificar e distinguir um substantivo de outro de mesma espécie, então ela é um adjetivo. E assim sucessivamente.  Portanto, seria fácil para a gramática classificar todas as palavras de uma determinada língua e tudo estaria resolvido. Seria? Acontece, porém, que uma série de palavrinhas, rebeldes, se negam a se enquadrar nesta ou naquela classificação. Quando se diz, por exemplo, “Só ela esteve aqui.”, como se poderia classificar a palavrinha Só? Seria um advérbio? Uma preposição? Talvez um adjetivo, equivalente a sozinho? Não, não há como classificá-la dentro do rigor das dez classes gramaticais. Por isso, a gramática normativa teve de buscar uma solução fora do seu próprio rigor e apelou à Semântica. Só, no exemplo dado, é meramente uma palavrinha denotativa de exclusão. Exclusão? De quê? Quem ela exclui? “Só ela esteve aqui”. Essa tão pequena palavrinha exclui, semanticamente, qualquer pessoa ou elemento que não seja esse “ela”. A força está com o “Só”. No entanto, há quem queira ver esse “Só” dessa frase como palavra de inclusão, ao incluir exclusivamente “ela” na ação verbal. Fico com a exclusão mesmo. O mesmo fenômeno ocorre com uma série de palavrinhas, que mais denotam alguma coisa do que se prestam a alguma classificação de acordo com suas finalidades. Assim, há palavras que denotam inclusão (também, até, mesmo, etc.), exclusão (só, somente, apenas, etc.), situação (**o MAS** em expressões como **“Mas que golaço!”**).

Com esse adendo, não pretendo dizer que essa é a resposta correta. Pode estar completamente errada. Exponho o texto aqui apenas como alimento para o raciocínio de quem está respondendo à pergunta.   Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Então, acho que é interjeição mesmo.

Comment: Muito interessante o adendo. Isso significaria que, de acordo com ele, não poderíamos usar classe gramatical alguma, mas apenas "palavrinha denotativa de exclusão"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/ent%C3%A3o/) coloca como uma das acepções de `então`, como **interjeição**:

> 2 Denota confirmação, servindo para corroborar a veracidade daquilo que se afirmou antes

que, numa pergunta, no meu entendimento se converte em "solicita confirmação", ao invés de "denota".

Mas talvez não seja de se descartar que ele possa ser visto como **advérbio**, caso o "então" possa ser substituído por "sendo assim", "nesse caso":

> 2 Nesse caso; nessa situação: Ganhou um bom dinheiro, então se deu ao luxo de comprar um carrão.

Comment: Acrescentei um novo conceito à pergunta.

Comment: @Centaurus, obrigado por chamar a atenção ao adendo.

Answer (score 0):

Como neste caso existe uma clara correlação entre as orações, eu vejo o termo "então" como uma conjunção (conclusiva). A proposta de desligar o ar-condicionado está baseada na premissa de que não está fazendo calor suficiente para que este permaneça ligado. Assim, o termo então mostra uma relação direta da última oração com a anterior, uma relação de conclusão.

Exemplo de uso como advérbio: Eu comi todo meu sanduíche e, então, bebi meu suco.

Neste caso, pode ter valor de interjeição: Então, o que você vai fazer este fim de semana?

Comment: Acrescentei um novo conceito à pergunta.